# Simultaneous user accounts using remote desktop / LMI

Tags: remote-desktop, accounts

I'm taking remote control (from Linux / Chrome) of an OS X system using LMI ("Log Me In").

I have two users account on this machine: one for when I'm physically in front of the system (the "main" user account) and one for when I'm connecting using LMI.

I'd like to know first if it would be possible to use both accounts simultaneously?  In other words: can someone work physically at the computer under one user account while I'm using the machine remotely using the second account?

If it's possible, is it possible to use both accounts using different screen size?

In case it's not possible, is it possible to configure the computer so that when I log from user account I get the native resolution and when I log in from the other user account I get a smaller resolution?

Basically I'd like the main account to use the native resolution of the monitor physically attached to the computer while the second account would be using a much smaller resolution.

I know this is trivial to do using Linux (no flamewars) but I don't know at all how this kind of stuff works on the OS X side of the pond.

*Note that I do not want to install an X server on OS X*