# Is it possible to have many simultaneous remote desktop sessions in MacOS?

Tags: macos, remote-desktop

I  maintain a 40 seat lab of iMac's can't be used due to the pandemic, but people who still need access to MacOS to do their work. For Windows, we are solving this problem with a server that supports multiple RDP sessions. Is there a similar way to serve many desktop sessions in MacOS (server)?

Notes:

- I would anticipate buying a MacPro to support this kind of workload.
- It is possible (but inconvenient) for me to physically access the lab, but approvals are required so each visit takes time to arrange.

PS: There is another ancient orphan question ([Simultaneous user accounts using remote desktop / LMI](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/56399/simultaneous-user-accounts-using-remote-desktop-lmi)
) about supporting 1 local and 1 remote user simultaneously, but that isn't my use case.

Comment: I assume the users can‘t remote login into one of the 40 iMacs?

Comment: @nohillside That would be my backup plan, but there are some annoying management challenges to solve.